# Circumvent Argument list too long in script (for loop)

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I've seen a few answers regarding this, but as a newbie, I don't really understand how to implement that in my script.

it should be pretty easy (for those who can stuff like this)

I'm using a simple

```
for f in "/drive1/"images*.{jpg,png}; do
```

but this is simply overloading and giving me

```
Argument list too long
```

How is this easiest solved?

Comment: There shouldn't be an argument limit here. Can you please try again with just `true` as a loop body, and without passing any arguments to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *Argument list too long* workaroud

Argument list length is something limited by your config.

```
getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

But after discuss around differences between [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) specifics and system (os) limitations  (see [comments from that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65071471/1765658#comment115053456_65071595)), this question seem wrong:

Regarding discuss on comments, OP tried something like:

```
ls "/simple path"/image*.{jpg,png} | wc -l
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

This happen because of OS limitation, not [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)!!

But tested with OP code, this work finely

```
for file in ./"simple path"/image*.{jpg,png} ;do echo -n a;done | wc -c
70980
```

Like:

```
printf "%c" ./"simple path"/image*.{jpg,png} | wc -c
```

### Reduce line length by reducing *fixed part*:

First step: you could reduce argument length by:

```
cd "/drive1/"
ls images*.{jpg,png} | wc -l
```

But when number of file will grow, you'll be buggy again...

### More general workaround:

```
find "/drive1/" -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -exec myscript {} +
```

If you want this to NOT be recursive, you may add `-maxdepth` as 1st option:

```
find "/drive1/" -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) \
    -exec myscript {} +
```

There, `myscript` will by run with filenames as arguments. The command line for `myscript` is built up until it reaches a  system-defined  limit.

```
myscript /drive1/file1.jpg '/drive1/File Name2.png' /drive1/...
```

From `man find`:

> ```
>    -exec command {} +
>          This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
>          the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
>          each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca‐
>          tions of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
>          matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
>          that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
> ```

### Inscript sample

You could create your script like

```
#!/bin/bash

target=( "/drive1" "/Drive 2/Pictures" )

[[ $1 == --run ]] &&
    exec find "${target[@]}" -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) \
        -exec $0 {} +

for file ;do
    echo Process "$file"
done
```

Then you have to run this with `--run` as argument.

- work with **any** number of files! (Recursively! See `maxdepth` option)
- permit many `target`
- permit *spaces* and *special characters* in file and directrories names
- you could run same script directly on files, without `--run`:

  ```
  ./myscript hello world 'hello world'
  Process hello
  Process world
  Process hello world
  ```

### Using **pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)**

Using arrays, you could do things like:

```
allfiles=( "/drive 1"/images*.{jpg,png} )
[ -f "$allfiles" ] || { echo No file found.; exit ;}

echo Number of files: ${#allfiles[@]}

for file in "${allfiles[@]}";do
    echo Process "$file"
done
```

Comment: is it possible to increase the Arg max settings?, or would that crash everything?

Comment: I'm sorry but if you need to run the same command over 2,000,000 items multiple times I think your process is a bit flawed from the get-go. It also wouldn't fix the issue of what if this new limit is then breached? By breaking them into chunks is the better solution anyway. I would even go so far as perhaps changing your loop to be for dir in foo and then for files in bar, just to make it process smaller 'lists' as an easy work around.

Comment: @bobdylan I've got total around 2m, but in 300k directories, isn't there anyway to read until the arguments are full, and run those? (the files are moved later in the script) OR limit it so it only runs with 5k files each time?

Comment: @AdamLarsson You'd better to use resistant syntax! See my sample script to be run with `--run` as argument, or directly with `filename(s)`.

Comment: @F.Hauri I assume I can add more paths in the target variable?,  and the --run and $1 is changeable as variables?

Comment: Yes, you could add more path to target variable. Yes `--run` could be a variable, bot No: `$1` have to be 1st argument in command line.

Comment: @AdamLarsson If these answer match your need, don't miss to *accept* them!

Comment: @F.Hauri I meant, the --run can be changed to --jump, for example, and the $1 can be changed to $4 if --jump is the 4th Argument?

Comment: Hum yes, but what's your 1st arguments? See getopts...

Comment: Common unix tool aim to have *options* (or switches) **before** arguments. But you could invert meaning: `[ "$1" = "--process" ] || exec find "${target[@]}" -name -exec $0 --process {} +`

Comment: @F.Hauri Bash for loops are not restricted by ARG_MAX

Comment: @F.Hauri ARG_MAX is the limit of argv+envp passed to an execve call. Since a for loop by itself does not involve an execve call with the arguments, ARG_MAX doesn't apply. There is no limit that prevents you from looping over millions and millions of filenames, exceeding both the traditional 128k argument limit and the modern stacksize/4 limit.

Comment: @thatotherguy what about op question: `for file in /path/*.jpg` lead to *Argument list too long*? (not personely tested)

Comment: I think OP left out the relevant parts of the script or invocation. Maybe they secretly did `for f in $1` and called `./script "/drive1/"images*.{jpg,png};` but wanted to simplify before posting, or maybe they collect the filenames into a single variable for logging or execution purposes. @AdamLarsson, do you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @thatotherguy not any finished MCVE, but I've just tested the old way with a short code, by creating 500'000 files, and just running the "for f* code and now it didn't throw a "Arguments to long"

Comment: @thatotherguy I think you're right, I must have read the screen wrong, it's `jpgtotal=$( ls -1 "/drive1/"*.jpg | wc -l )`  that's causing it to fail..

Comment: Yep, that'll do it.

Comment: @thatotherguy anyway to get around that limitation?

Comment: You can use e.g. `find /drive1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -printf x | wc -c`

Comment: @thatotherguy seems to be works great, thx

Comment: It fails if filenames have spaces though

Comment: @thatotherguy Right! `printf "%c" test/* | wc -c` syntax will work even with spaces in filenames!

Comment: @thatotherguy I've edited my answer to reflect your comments and add a bash sample using *array*.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a while read loop:

```
find "/drive1/" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) |
while IFS= read -r file; do
```

or with zero terminated files:

```
find "/drive1/" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
```

Comment: Note that `-mindepth 1` is useless, because of `-type f`!!

Comment: Asking [tag:bash] to parse `find` output is a lot slower than running bash script with parsed arguments!! (On my rasbberry-pi (model B), with only 25'000 files, your solution take 40s vs 3s for my solution;)